# facebook api - what token do I need?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm developing a site for a non-profit. I'm building it as an express app hosted on heroku that needs access to the non-profits facebook group events.
I'm able to grab all the group's events in the graph api explorer. But I'm very confused as to what api token I need.

What facebook api token do I need to provide my webapp so it can access a random group's events listing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You want to use an app token. Easiest method is to create an app, then submit a get request with your app_id concatenated with your app secret.

Like so `curl https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret` note that `https` is required. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens

Note this only works for endpoints that don't need user credentials e.g. public groups https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/ However group/events does need a user access token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/group/events

Answer (score 2):

Probably the app access token from the application requesting the information.  The access token can be created by linking your application ID and your application secret together like so:

APP_ID | APP_SECRET

No spaces between though, just provided them for clarity.

PHP example:

```
$app_access_token=$app_id."|".$app_secret;
```

Then just append the access token to your request and it should work.

Comment: i agree, the app token is the best choice - just keep in mind that it will only work for public groups, of course. else you would need to use a user token of a user who is group member.

Comment: looks like you can just use the app id also instead of an app token https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#apptokens

Comment: Anything requiring an access token requires an app secret matching the application making the call.

Comment: @HarryMoreno Don't edit other people's answers to add information of your own.  You can add another comment or edit your original question with examples or questions.

Comment: @Phillip get over yourself. I was making the answer better.

Comment: @HarryMoreno then attribute the answer to yourself then, like you did below.  Then you get credit as the one adding the information, not me.